# EPPlus not caluculating formula output after binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, epplus

I am using EPPlus. I am stuck at cell formulas.

My code is below:

```
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(@"D:\MYSheets\EmptyFile.xlsx");
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];

ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "2.3";
ws.Cells["A4"].Value = "10.2";

ws.Cells["A5"].Formula = "=SUM(A3:A4)";
ws.Cells["A5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
pck.Save();
```

When I open Excel, by default, A5 cell is not calculating the sum of A3 and A4. Unless I modify the A3 and/or A4 cells, the A5 cell remains not calculated.

I tried using the following code but it didn't work for me:

```
ws.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
ws.Cells["A3"].Value = 2.3;
ws.Cells["A4"].Value = 10.2;
```

You were telling EPPlus to store the values as a string, that's why the formula failed.

Answer (score 1):

also replace

```
ws.Cells["A5"].Formula = "=SUM(A3:A4)";
```

with

```
ws.Cells["A5"].Formula = "SUM(A3:A4)";
```

to result value of A5

Answer (score -1):

perform Calculate() on the sheet, workbook or cell to ensure the formula executes.
https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation