# EPPlus formula: recalculated in LibreOffice, but NOT in SOME version of Excel

Tags: excel, formula, epplus

I've a C# database program and generate an Excel file (*.xlsx) with one sheet using EPPlus. The problem is that least a certain version of Excel does not recalculate the formulas while opening the document. I'm developing the app for somebody else and can tell you next week the exact version of Excel that shows the problem.

I'm not going to show my complete code, but a simple example that demonstrates the problem.
I've copied the example from here and adepted it a bit: [EPPlus not caluculating formula output after binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068387/epplus-not-caluculating-formula-output-after-binding)

Here is the code:

```
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");

            ws.Cells["A3"].Value = 2.3;
            ws.Cells["A4"].Value = 10.2;

            ws.Cells["A5"].Formula = "=SUM(A3:A4)";
            ws.Cells["A5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";

            ws.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\users\richard\tmp1.xlsx"));
        }
```

The document opens fine in LibreOffice. It opens also in (the yet unkown) Excel version, but the formula is not recalculated on opening.

I was reluctant to buy a license for MS Office, so I downloaded an Excel viewer first.
ExcelViewer.exe, File version 12.0.4518.1071. This viewer shows the same behaviour: the formula is not calculated.

So, very relunctantly, I purchased Office 365 Home Premium and guess what: this version of Excel DOES recalculate the formulas.

I think it is a bug in the Excel version, not in EPPlus or my code. But is there any workaround to force ALL versions of Excel to recalculate formula's?

And yes, I've tried to read all other relevant postings here, this is not a duplicate.

Many thanks.

Comment: @Charles Williams: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your reply tells me that you think Execel is not the cause and that setting the calculation mode is not sufficient, but it provides no solution or suggestion what more I should do. Please show me the error in the code above??? I've only ONE workbook and the above code sets the flag for THAT workbook.

Comment: Update: the version that does not recalculate the formulas is Excel 2010. And also the the free Excel viewer has this behaviour.

Comment: Then I've read many comments on SO and setting the Calculation mode seems to be the way to go. Also XlsxWriter sets all outcomes of formulas to zero and then sets "a flag" (I expect this to be the calculation mode) to force recalculation. This works in LibreOffice and Excel 2013, but not in Excel 2010. Anyway, we have decided to either write computed values in our reports (uggh!) OR to use LibreOffice, since an update to Excel 2013 is too expensive. Thank you all.

Comment: @Charles Williams, quote: And BTW I don't see how you expect to successfully create Excel files without being able to test them. 1) The doccuments are rather simple and I had expected the same behaviour in Excel and LibreOffice. 2) I could test with the viewer. 3) since I develop free of charge (its for my brother) I did not want to make any costs. But I ultimately bought a license for the 2013 version. I did not feel like buying a license for an older version. In Excel 2013 it works fine though.

Comment: I cannot comment on the EPPlus "flag" without knowing what Excel property it is supposed to set. As I said - setting calculation mode in a workbook only sets the Excel calculation mode if its the first workbook opened in an excel session. I suggest you tell your end-user to press Ctrl/Alt/F9 in Excel after opening your generated file. Or generate some VBA  in the file to trigger a calculation at workbook open. Or tell your user to make sure that Excel is in Automatic calculation mode when your file is opened.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is likely to be an Excel bug, its would be so fundamental that everyone would know about it. 
Generating an XL XML file does not calculate formulas. 
Viewing an Excel file in a viewer does not calculate formulas.
 Setting a workbook calculation mode to Automatic does not neccessarily mean that Excel will be in Automatic Calculation mode: 
Calculation mode is an Excel session instance setting taken from the first workbook opened so if Excel is in Manual mode when your workbook is opened it won't calculate.
 (And BTW I don't see how you expect to successfully create Excel files without being able to test them)